# Image hosting site with custom link addresses

Tags: android, facebook, image

I have an android game that allows the user to post to their facebook wall if they are having trouble on a level. I have the functionality of the facebook posting process working if i link an image from a hosting website instead of uploading it from my app. The reason I am doing this is to save time on loading the facebook post and i could not get the image uploader to work correctly.

I have over 900 levels with each level containing 1 image. I have written the following code for when the user clicks on the facebook button.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("link", getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_link));
    params.putString("name", getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_achievement_title_1)+" "+getLevel()+" "+getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_achievement_title_2));
    params.putString("caption", getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_caption));
    params.putString("description", getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_achievement_text_1)+" "+getLevel()+getResources().getString(R.string.msg_facebook_achievement_text_2));
    params.putString("picture", "http://i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/" + getLevel() + ".png");
```

Although, i cannot find an image hosting site that gives the link address of the image uploaded. They all create custom addresses for every image. For example i am looking for address like this:

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/1.png

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/2.png

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/3.png

but i am given address like this:

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/fweh78932bfa.png

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/83ja893ha99f.png

http: //i26.photobucket.com/albums/c106/fj9321la01km.png

which obviously will not work with my code. Are there any free sites that will make this work? I don't want to write a switch and case method for 900 custom addresses. If not, is their any other way to make this work without writing 900 indiviual level codes?

Comment: Why not host it yourself in whatever URLs you choose?

Comment: hosting myself will cost website server fees, im am after a free alternative

Comment: Beggars can't be choosers. If you put it on something like Amazon S3 chances are you'd only be paying pennies.